# how to set values to OUT args of a postgres stored function

Tags: postgresql

This function is not compiling (syntax error at or near "f1" Position: 92), it illustrates as pseudo code what I want to achieve :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tmp_my_func(x INTEGER, OUT f1 INTEGER, OUT f2 INTEGER)
AS $$
      f1 := x*2;
      f2 := x*3;    
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tmp_my_func(x INTEGER, OUT f1 INTEGER, OUT f2 INTEGER)
AS $BODY$
begin 
   select x*2, x*3 into f1, f2;
end       
$BODY$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;


SELECT z.f1, z.f2 from tmp_my_func(1) z;
```

will return 2, 3

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `LANGUAGE sql`, it has to be an SQL statement

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tmp_my_func(x integer, OUT f1 integer, OUT f2 integer)
   LANGUAGE sql AS
'SELECT x*2, x*3';
```

In PL/pgSQL it could look like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tmp_my_func(x integer, OUT f1 integer, OUT f2 integer)
   LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
'BEGIN
   f1 := 2*x;
   f2 := 3*x;
END;';
```